# trouble trusting https certificates for .net 6

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up a web app project in visual studio 2022 and when I run it asks me to trust SSL and it says there was an error trusting and always start in untrusted mode in the browser.
I tried running
`dotnet dev-certs https --clean`
`dotnet dev-certs https --trust`
but I get an output saying there was an error trusting https certificates.

These are the details if I run info if it matters:

```
dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.400
 Commit:    7771abd614

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19043
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.120 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the suggestions written in this post and nothing worked. Re-installed windows and now I got no issues with certificates.
It ain't stupid if it works?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. After running the codes you specified. I restarted my computer and problem solved.

Also, when you run the project again, the option to trust SSL certificate should appear.
You must select yes for both options.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayjjU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7rfQ.png)

Comment: i restarted and it didnt make a difference, reinstalled .net 6, reinstalled visual studio and of course selected yes on the pop ups but i still get errors 'failed trusting the certificate'.

Answer (score 0):

For problems getting an untrusted certificate warning, you can try using a PowerShell script.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/installation/warnings-untrusted-certificate#method-1-use-a-powershell-script

Another way is to configure the computer to trust the IIS Express certificate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/installation/warnings-untrusted-certificate#method-2-configure-computers-to-trust-the-iis-express-certificate